# Search ListView items based on DataGridView text box value change event. matched item should be selected and same time text box focus should not leave

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

I am having c# (windows application) Datagridview with 4 columns. Having text box as one of column in grid. when i type letters in Text box, based on Text, listview Popup will select first item.

1 . when i press enter button selected listview item should be posted in grid.

2. When i move up/down arrow it should navigate next listview item.
3. Always focus should be in Text box, always accept user input.
   I tried with key events, but i need some new ideas

For list view focus i written code like below

old Post:
Search ListView items based on DataGridView text box value change event, matched item should be selected in ListView and same time should not leave text box focus.

DataGridView text box change event has code like below:

```
listView1.Select();
listView1.EnsureVisible(list.Index);
listView1.Items[list.Index].Selected = true;
listView1.Focus();
```

Comment: Can you please describe more about your problem. Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Mohamad, i have edited post. hope you can get my question